# Book Mastering Grunt Chapeter 1 Bower problems

Tags: bower

When I try the examples from the [book](http://www.packtpub.com/mastering-grunt/book) i get lots of error and nothing gets installed. What am I missing, when looking for examples on the the internet my bower.json looks ok.

Se this [link](http://lpaste.net/108258) for code and more info:

Comment: are you running bower from a network drive? Try running this locally first.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/bower/bower/pull/1403) with a tmp dependency. Bower has since been updated though to fix it (build 1.3.8). I see you still have an older version. Please run

```
npm update -g bower
```

to update bower to the final release and try again.